# How to view [Circular] in Node?

Tags: node.js, console.log

In my console, I'm getting:

```
{
  'a': [Circular],
  'b': [Circular],
  'c': [Circular]
}
```

How can I see the contents of `[Circular]`? I've tried `console.log()`, `util.inspect()` and `console.dir()` and I'm still getting `[Circular]` instead of the actual content.

Edit:
I'm trying to see the actual content, how many layers deep it goes, etc., for debugging purposes. Linked question does not address any of that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Nodejs, when I console.log a req object, what does \[Circular\] reference? How to determine that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010173/in-nodejs-when-i-console-log-a-req-object-what-does-circular-reference-how)

Comment: I'm trying to see the actual content, how many layers deep it goes, etc., for debugging purposes. Linked question does not address any of that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically that's recursion, as far as I know there is no way to possibly log a [Circular] reference (don't quote me on that), but if you could it would probably be like this:

```
{
  'a': {
    'a': {
      'a':{
        // never ending
      }
    }
  }
}
```